# How to specify the registry before installing the dependent packages in Azure Function (javascript)?

Tags: azure-functions

I chose the Local Git deployment method using Azure Fcuntion. My programming language is javascript. When I upload the code from local machine to Azure Functions by using Git, the 'node_moudle' directory is not uploaded, so I have a few questions to know:

1. Will 'npm install' be executed after uploading the code?
2. During the execution of 'npm install', which registry is the dependency package pulled from？
3. How to specify the registry in this process?

Thanks.

Refrence doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies

Comment: Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#dependency-management

Comment: Yes, I got a answer from this doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [yonding701](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17202359/yongding701) for confirming. Glad that your issue is resolved posting it as an answer to help the other community members.

In order to use the libraries in your JavaScript you need to ensure that all the dependencies are installed on your function app.

Below is the sample code for installing dependencies

```
// Import the underscore.js library
var _ = require('underscore');
var version = process.version; // version === 'v6.5.0'

module.exports = function(context) {
    // Using our imported underscore.js library
    var matched_names = _
        .where(context.bindings.myInput.names, {first: 'Carla'});
```

Check this [Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#dependency-management) link for further details.